# How to : Use Powershell and Install Windows 7 via Wi-Fi

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, deployment

I dont know much about ITs Professionals but I hear that is possible to join many laptops on a WLAN or LAN and then install and deploy windows 7 on all machines via Powershell using scriptlets. How can I learn to do that and please tell me your experiences.

I want to do it for an Event like a BootCamp

Maybe I have to install Windows Server 2008 R2 on one machine and then the others join to a domain or workgroup and deploy via cmdlets?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There ***are*** solutions to automatically deploy Windows to machines without an installed O.S., but they usually require the client to be able to boot from LAN using a protocol called PXE; this is normally supported on all recent Ethernet cards, but I've never heard of a computer able to boot from WI-FI.

If you can put down the WI-FI requirement, then this can be set up quite easily for basic deployment; you'll only need an Active Directory domain and a server which will run the Windows Deployment Services.

If you want more control over the automatic deployment, you should have a look at the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit.

Some links:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771670(WS.10).aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/desktopdeployment/default.aspx

PowerShell is totally unrelated to all of this, actually; I don't know why you heard of it being involved.